# Argument $\int_{-\infty}^{t}\int_{-\infty}^{x_2}f_{X_1,X_2}dx_1dx_2=\int_{-\infty}^{t}\int_{-\infty}^{x_1}f_{X_1,X_2}dx_2dx_1$

Tags: integration, density-function

Right now I have two integrals
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{t} \int_{-\infty}^{x_2} f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) \, dx_1 dx_2 =
\int_{-\infty}^{t} \int_{-\infty}^{x_1} f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) \, dx_2 dx_1
$$
with the property that $f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)=f_{X_1,X_2}(x_2,x_1)$ for all possible $(x_1,x_2)$. This intuitively make sense if I just draw the area bounded by these two integrals, but I am writing a proof right now and really don't know how can I formally explain it. Some hint would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By swapping the names of the variables $(x_1, x_2) \leftrightarrow (x_2, x_1)$ in the first expression, you *almost* get the second equation. But the arguments of the function are now swapped. Fortunately, you have the hypothesis that your function is symmetric in those arguments, so
$$
\def\cb#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
\def\cg#1{\color{green}{#1}}
\begin{align*}
\cb{\int_{-\infty}^{t}} \cg{\int_{-\infty}^{x_2}} 
f_{X_1,X_2}(\cg{x_1}, \cb{x_2}) \, \cg{dx_1} \cb{dx_2} 
&= \cg{\int_{-\infty}^{t}} \cb{\int_{-\infty}^{x_1}} 
f_{X_1,X_2}(\cb{x_2}, \cg{x_1}) \, \cb{dx_2} \cg{dx_1} \\
&= \cg{\int_{-\infty}^{t}} \cb{\int_{-\infty}^{x_1}} 
f_{X_1,X_2}(\cg{x_1}, \cb{x_2}) \, \cb{dx_2} \cg{dx_1}. 
\end{align*} 
$$

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand your notation. How can you use $x_1$ and $x_2$ as variables of integration and as limits of integration?

Comment: Use dollar signs to wrap $\LaTeX$ in math mode: `$x_1$`, etc.

Comment: This is completely standard with multiple integrals. Notice that it never happens that a particular variable is the limit of integration for the variable you're integrating over.